# VB6 - Tabbing between textboxes. How to get cursor focus always at the end of the textbox value

Tags: vb6, textbox

I have a form with a series of textboxes each of which can be 8 digits long. I have a button that cycles through the form and fills in the first four digits (0123). When I tab between the textboxes, how can I always have the cursor focus go the end of the line, that is, after the fourth digit? Thanks :)

Comment: You now have 2 good answers. One always puts the cursor after the 4th digit, even if the text is longer. One always puts the cursor at the end regardless of how long the text is: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or whatever. Just decide which you prefer!

Comment: Both solutions set cursor when mouse activating too. OP wants selection changed on tabbing only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place this code in your form's source file.

```
Private Sub Text1_GotFocus()
    Text1.SelStart = Len(Text1.Text)
End Sub
```

This assumes that you have a textbox named Text1. When it has the focus, the cursor is placed at the end of the textbox.

Answer (score 3):

```
Private Sub Text1_GotFocus()
  Text1.SelStart = 4
End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldnt it be 4? 0 is the start, 1 is after the 1st digit, etc. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445679(v=VS.60).aspx

Comment: @MarkJ Yes, it should be. For some reason I thought the default contents, `text1`, is four characters long.

Comment: +1. Worth mentioning that for less than 4 characters this code puts the cursor at the end of the text.

Answer (score 1):

If wqw's point is correct, and you only want this on tab press and not when clicking with the mouse then you would combine the existing answers with the forms_KeyUp event, if the  key up is 9 then this is the tab button and you could then invoke the Selstart method.

Comment: right, the Tab press is definitely the number one thing, thanks for the help on this

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you have a series of textboxes you could use a single method to set the cursor position to the end of the textbox for every control on Form_Load.  This would require a lot less code than an event handler for each and every textbox.

```
Dim o As Variant
For Each o In Form1.Controls
    If TypeName(o) = "TextBox" Then
        Dim x As TextBox
        Set x = o
        x.SelStart = Len(x.Text)
    End If
Next
```

However, when a user changes the cursor position in any of the text boxes it will remain changed when they leave and come back to the textbox.  Depending upon your scenario this may or may not be the desired behaviour. For example, the first time any textbox gets focus, the cursor is at the end.  If the user decides to change the cursor position and leave and come back to the same textbox the cursor is where they left it.